# jQuery UI resizable - do not set the height when resizing the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, resize

Problem: When I resize the width of my table column (resize is bound on the table header), the jQuery UI sets the style attribute `height` into the html element and substracts -1px of the height. When I resize the header multiple times, the table header disappears:

[image: Table header disappears after resize]

The JavaScript code snipped:

```
$("#t-th-1").resizable({
    minWidth: 100,
    maxWidth: null,
    helper: "resizable-helper",
    handles: "e",
    stop: function (event, ui) {

        // execution code
    }
});
```

The HTML code snipped:

```
<div id="t-th-1" class="t-th">
    <span>Name</span>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; height: 360px;"></div>
</div>
```

After an resize action:

```
<div id="t-th-1" class="t-th" style="width: 239px; height: 14px">
    <span>Name</span>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; height: 360px;"></div>
</div>
```

The original table header element has and height of 15px. But after resizing, it becomes 14px.

How can I prevent setting the height?

Comment: The -1 px is intentional, I recall looking it up for another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342073/ I still haven't found another way around it other than resetting the `height` manually